# Props aren't rendering on the page or in React Dev tools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have a hard time understanding react props and mapping data from an array and can't get the props to render on my Card component, nor can I get them to display in the react dev tools. It's unclear to me where I'm going wrong. Please help if you can spot where I'm going wrong. I also get an error 'createCard' is defined but never used ? Though I actually pass that function into map function in App.jsx .... Also in the browser I get an error that reads "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop ", isn't the keys assigned to array all unique?

Card.jsx file:

```
    import React from "react";
    
    



function Card (props) {
  return (
     <div>
        <div className="link-container">
         
            <div className="row">
                <div className="card">
                <hr className="divide"></hr>
                <img className="img" src={props.img} alt="social-icon" />
                <h4 className="name">{props.name}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            </div>
                     
     </div>

  )

}

    export default Card;
```

app.jsx file:

```
    import Header from "./Header";
    import Card from  "./Card";
    import links from "../links";

    function createCard (socialLinks) {
  return <Card

  key = {socialLinks.id}
  img = {socialLinks.img}
  name = {socialLinks.name}
  href = {socialLinks.href}
  
/>
}

    function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      {
        links.map((createCard) => (
          <Card />
        ))
      }
     
      
      
       
   
    </div>
   
  );
}

export default App;
```

links.js file:

```
 const links = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Youtube",
        img:"./img/youtube1.svg",
        href: "https://www.youtube.com/c/SubwaySounds"

    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Spotify",
        img:"./img/spotify.svg",
        href: "https://artists.spotify.com/c/artist/3DM32kjsG7Pp5EM7o3Uv7t/profile/overview"

    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Tiktok",
        img:"./img/tiktok.svg",
        href: "https://www.tiktok.com/@nysubwaysounds"

    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Instagram",
        img:"./img/Instagram1.svg",
        href: "https://www.instagram.com/nycsubwaysounds/?hl=en"

    },

    {
        id: 5,
        name: "Shop",
        img:"./img/shop.svg",
        href: "https://my-store-11524143.creator-spring.com/"

    }
    

]

export default links;
```

Comment: You don't pass any props to `<Card>` in the mapping function. Also, in addition to props expected by `Card` you need to set the unique `key` prop. You can use the `id` of each link.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the function correctly in App.jsx. `createCards` in the map is simply the name of the argument of the function, but you can just use the function directly inside the map:

```
function createCard (socialLink) {
  return <Card
    key = {socialLink.id}
    img = {socialLink.img}
    name = {socialLink.name}
    href = {socialLink.href}
  />
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      {
        links.map(createCard)
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also remember inside of a map function you'll be getting each element from the array individually, so I changed the name of the argument in the function from `socialLinks` to `socialLink` so it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The Card component and link file looks fine, some changes to be made to the App.jsx

```
import Header from "./Header";
    import Card from  "./Card";
    import links from "../links";

    function CreateCard (socialLinks) {
  return <Card

  key = {socialLinks.id}
  img = {socialLinks.img}
  name = {socialLinks.name}
  href = {socialLinks.href}
  
/>
}

    function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      {
        links.map((link) => (
         <CreateCard 
           key={link.id} 
           img={link.img}
           name={link.name}
           href={link.href}
          />
        ))
      }
    </div>
   
  );
}

export default App;
```

So mapping each link and passing the attributes would solve the keys issue and the unused CreateCard